# Consume .NET WCF Service in Eclipse for Blackberry

Tags: eclipse, wcf, blackberry

does consume .NET WCF service is do-able in Eclipse for Blackberry?

been trying hard for 4 days now with no luck
i'm stuck when trying to generate java Stub class for my WCF using Java ME 3.2
because my WCF contain .NET List as parameter and for unknown reason Java ME can't generate those stub for me :(

Why?
any insight?

thx,
erick

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that you could change / check:

- Change your contract to use types that are valid across platforms. Change your .net lists to arrays.
- Do not return a lists directly. create a return object that has a property which has a list.
- Make sure that you are using a WCF configuration that is compatible with the calling platform, for example basic http binding.
- Make sure that wsdl generation is turned on
- Make sure that your service is running

You should test your service from a .net client first, to ensure that it is a compatibility problem.

If you have something like:

```
  public myItems[] GetData();
```

Try;

```
  [OperationContract]
  public myResponse GetData();


  [DataContract]
  public class myResponse()
  {
      [Datamember]
      myItems[] items { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: hx shiraz for ur insight Change your contract to use types that are valid across platforms -> any recommended further reading? i've try replace List to Array in WCF but still it can't create the stub for me.. 

WSDL already on, service is also running (deployed it to local IIS) already test with .net client too (using UnitTest) and it ended up successfully (data created in SQL)

Comment: Try wraping the array in a response object, which binding are you using? Which error od you get?

Comment: Try wraping the array in a response object -> meaning?

if i'm using .net client, there is no error
when try to generate java stub from WSDL using JavaME, the stub not generated

Comment: Shiraz: i can generate the stub using ur method, i think i know why it's happened

all must refer to this document: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webservices-138799.html

those are known type that supported by Java ME, because the limitation of mobile platform i believe

for my case: i'm using WCF and Entity Framework which i thought i have to create another wrapper class like yours but this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586297/wcf-contracts-from-entity-framework) said that Entity Model type already DataContract so i just can straight use it

Comment: and also i think WCF must not use Entity Relation because it will break in java ME (plz confirm me about this one)

so i have to set extra logic manually for the Entity Relation

any other insights?

Comment: In this case we would not expose the EF objects unless they were POCO. We would create Data Transfer Objects and use them in the WCF contracts.

Comment: i believe .net 4.5 entity model already POCO because when i generate it, it will create object of my Entity ( .tt )

We would create Data Transfer Objects and use them in the WCF contracts. -> can u give example on this one?

Comment: hmm, are DTO is like creating new Class that wrap with fields like my EF that will be converted to my EF model?